# How do I change the style of the map in a navigation view?

Tags: android, navigation, styles, mapbox

I am implementing the mapbox maps and the mapbox navigation by using these imports:

```
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.5.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.42.6'
```

I have map with a self made map style, from which I select a destination location and launch the navigation activity.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean simulateRoute = false;
                        NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
                                .directionsRoute(currentRoute)
                                .shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute)
                                .build();
                        // Call this method with Context from within an Activity
                        NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(NavigationActivity.this, options);
                    }
                });
```

The navigation activity displays a map that has a style that does not match the one I used in the map that I used to start the navigation activity. How can I change the style of the map in the navigation view to match the one I used for the map that selected the destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's (fortunately) not too tricky to do - it's a matter of creating a new style (in styles.xml) for this purpose.

Something like this: ([an excerpt from Mapbox's guides/documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-navigation-sdk/))

[**style.xml**]

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<!-- Mapbox Navigation style. Loads more items can be styled simply by adding them below. -->    
<style name="NavigationView" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="navigationViewPrimary">@color/mapboxWhite</item>
    <item name="navigationViewSecondary">@color/mapboxBlue</item>
    <item name="navigationViewAccent">@color/mapboxPink</item>
</style>
```

As mentioned in the code excerpt above, it is possible to style a lot (almost all) of the UI using the method above. An in-depth rundown of what's possible when it comes to styling the Navigation UI SDK can be found at the following URL:
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/guides/styles/

In addition to the above, it appears to be possible to specify both light and dark styles via the NavigationLauncherOptions.Builder, if that's something of interest. Further info on that, [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/api/ui/0.42.6/com/mapbox/services/android/navigation/ui/v5/NavigationLauncherOptions.Builder.html).

I sincerely hope that helps, and welcome to SO!

Comment: Oh OK, thank you for that very elaborate answer. I'm sorry I didn't express myself clearly. I was wondering if there was a way that I could use a style uri or link for a style created in Mapbox studio to change the style of the map in the navigation view.

Comment: @TheCmart unfortunately passing a style to the navigation view is not possible as far as I'm aware. The method that I've outlined above works, but it's a bit of a pain to step through your existing map style and copy across individual colours and such.

Comment: OK I understand. Thank you for your swift response.

Comment: No problem @TheCmart, take care and best of luck moving forward with your project